# FingerPrint Authentication option in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, winjs

I'm using the CredentiapPicker Api and im not getting a fingerprint scanner option in the picker for windows 8 project even though i have fingerprint support with drivers installed. lenovo have seperate drivers for windows 8 so it cant be that its not supported in 8.Am i doing something wrong.

```
var credentialPickerOptions = new Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.CredentialPickerOptions();
credentialPickerOptions.targetName = "My App";
credentialPickerOptions.caption = "My App";
credentialPickerOptions.message = "Sign in to My App";
credentialPickerOptions.authenticationProtocol = Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.AuthenticationProtocol.basic;
credentialPickerOptions.alwaysDisplayDialog = true;
var credentialPicker = Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.CredentialPicker;
credentialPicker.pickAsync(credentialPickerOptions).done(function () {
    alert("done");


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be using Basic authentication against the fingerprint reader.  Normally corporate credentials will be negotiate, kerberos or NTLM.  Try switching to that and ensure you have a fingerprint registered for you login.

There is no option to change the appearance of that dialog other than the documented options here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.ui.credentialpickeroptions.aspx

Comment: Thanks negotiate, kerberos or NTLM works. I get username password display on the left and fingerprint on the right. But is there a way to only display fingerprint in the chooser display.